# IE11: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid in my angularjs application. And populate it with more than 100000 records with 15 columns. And have to generate the grid again and again according to some filtering.

It works perfectly in chrome and firefox, but in IE11 I can only generate the grid couple of times. after multiple grid generations, it causes  "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation" error message

> Error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. at xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8510:11)"

Comment: Are you storing any data in the browser's localStorage or sessionStorage?

Comment: @DavidWalschots Just store on a local variable in the controller and in each regenerate that variable is updated.

Comment: Anyone found a solution ? Facing the same problem while trying yo parse soap response containing a longer base64 string (getting error for files larger then 6mB)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please share code snippet ..

Anyway few questions:

1. Why dont you have paging ?
2. Why you need to bring more than 100 (at max) rows on UI ?

Try changing below setting highlighted on Image.
Click "Setting" under Browsing history to see this tab.

[image]

Comment: Data is retried from a 3rd party application. Which I doesn't have control. So cannot implement a pagination. And have display those amount of records as per the req

Comment: It is possible that Disk space allowed for IE is full or data size is more.. Though if its not enought you application is not efficient. Please try changing clearing IE cache and temp files along with with allocating more memory in Disk space usage

Comment: I tried changing that setting as well. But no luck.